# How to monitor process behavior in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, process

In Windows, we can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) and [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645). Can we do similar task in Mac OS X?

For example, if I want to monitor a process which will execute another process with specified arguments, how can I get that?

Answer (score 1):

**Mac OS X System Monitor and Process Explorer Tool**

> atMonitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Mac OS X that displays
>   system activity in real-time. It is designed to allow quick assessment
>   of computer's state and it is powerful enough to make it a core
>   utility in anyone's system troubleshooting toolkit. atMonitor offers a
>   better alternative to Apple's own "Activity Monitor" and combines the
>   best of the features of many other existing monitoring utilities. It
>   also adds an extensive list of unique features of its own. In addition
>   to the standard CPU, Disk and Network info, atMonitor allows
>   interaction with processes, setting up triggers, logging, purging RAM
>   and much more. atMonitor can be displayed in the menu bar, as a stand
>   alone floating window or in the dock icon. The last version of
>   atMonitor to support GPU related features is atMonitor 2.7.1. The last
>   version of atMonitor to support PPC is atMonitor 2.1.5, which is no
>   longer supported, but available for those with PPC based Macs.

http://www.atpurpose.com/atMonitor/

**Also see:**

[Peek-a-boo](http://www.clarkwood.com/peekaboo)

[iStat pro](http://www.islayer.net/viewWidget.php?id=7)

[iStat menus](http://islayer.com/index.php?op=item&id=28)

[MenuMeters](http://www.ragingmenace.com/)

[XRG](http://www.gauchosoft.com/Products/)

http://alternativeto.net/software/process-explorer/?platform=mac